# JavaScript, json to excel (exceljs)

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I have to maintain a code that do a weird and slow loops.

Currently it's looping in a while each object from a JSON like this one (example JSON):

```
[
  {
    ID: 1,
    NAME: 'A'
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    NAME: 'D'
  },{
    ID: 5,
    NAME: 'etc'
  }
]
```

And it's creating an excel file with `exceljs` library but as I said, with some loops that I consider really unnecesary.

The idea is to create an excel file like this:

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  |  A
3  |  D
5  |  etc
```

So I wonder if there's a direct way with `exceljs` or another Excel library for NodeJS to create a simple excel file from a JSON, where each key of the JSON be a header value, and each value of thos key: value pairs be the value of the cell in the excel?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer by @davidhu doesn't work. You'll have to setup the columns before adding the rows as a JSON:

```js
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');

worksheet.columns = [
  { letter: 'A', header: 'ID', key: 'ID' },
  { letter: 'B', header: 'NAME', key: 'NAME' },
];

const rows = [
  { ID: 1, NAME: 'A' },
  { ID: 3, NAME: 'D' },
  { ID: 5, NAME: 'etc' },
];

const newRows = worksheet.addRows(rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just add the json array

```js
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');

const rows = [
  {
    ID: 1,
    NAME: 'A'
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    NAME: 'D'
  },{
    ID: 5,
    NAME: 'etc'
  }
]

const newRows = worksheet.addRows(rows);
```

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#add-rows